# Switching elements in a list by n. Help improving

Tags: python

So I have made two functions that do similar jobs. I would just like to know if there are any improvements I should make since I'm fairly new to python but have done a little bit of C# back in the day. Downvotes are appreciated.

Function 1 reverses whatever string you put in and separates it into a list by spaces:

```
sentence = "A B C D E F G"

def splitAndReverse(string):            #reverses the list
    split = string.split(" ")
    lastIndex = len(split) - 1
    newList = []                        #empty list to assign to in the for loop

    print(f"Your list: \n{split}")

    for i in split:
        reverseIndex = lastIndex - split.index(i)   #last index backward
        newList.append(split[reverseIndex])         #add to the list from the end to the beginning

    print(f"Reversed list: \n{newList}")

splitAndReverse(sentence)

Your list: 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
Reversed list: 
['G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Function 2 swaps each element from the beginning and the end by "n" until it reaches the middle:

```
def switchFunction(string):             #Switches every first and last index incremented by i+-
    split = string.split(" ")           #and then stops in the middle so they don't
    lastIndex = len(split) - 1          #switch twice
    halfOfSplit = int(len(split) / 2)

    print(f"Original list: \n{split}")

    for i in range(halfOfSplit):
        reverseIndex = lastIndex - i    #switch positions by first and last index
        forwardIndex = i                #by either increment or decrement

        split[forwardIndex], split[reverseIndex] = split[reverseIndex], split[forwardIndex]

    print(f"New list swaped: \n{split}")

switchFunction(sentence)

Original list: 
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
New list swaped: 
['G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: If the code is complete and works, it should be on [codereview.se]. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for clarification.

Comment: You can just do `reversed(string.split(" "))` (that gives you an iterator, wrap it with `list(...)` to produce a proper list object).

Comment: Of course giving a variable the same name as the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) isn't the best of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Function 1:

```
def splitAndReverse(string):      
    return string.split()[::-1]
```

Comment: PS. Function 2 does exactly the same job as function 1, so you don't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly the complexity of the any waay would be O(n) where n is the number of the chars in the string, and you functions are also like this.

You can improve it with some tricks but it wont change the complexity.

When you do `string.split(" ")` it passes over the string once,
and then you pass it again in your `for` loop.

few suggestions that you can use in order to pass only once ( python have more things to iterate over collection than most of the languages ) so you can use them.

For example a function that skip the space char so you wont have to do `string.split(" ")` :

```
sentence = "A B C D E F G"

def reverse_to_list(word):
    return [c for c in word[::-2]]
    
print(reverse_to_list(sentence))
```

Output :

```
['G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```